# JAXB Map String to Enum Values in Generated XSD

Tags: enums, jaxb

I have a simple POJO with a String property. This String property actually contains values backed by a Java Enum. For reasons that I won't go into here, I can't just use the enum type on my POJO. Is there any JAXB annotation I can use on the String property such that when the XSD is generated, I have the values restricted to the the backing list of Enum values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use an `XmlAdapter` for this use case:

```
public class MyEnumAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MyEnum, String> {
   ...
}
```

Then on your class register the `XmlAdapter` on the `String` property that corresponds to the enum.

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyEnumAdapter.class)
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Worked great! I only had to add an XmlType annotation to my enum so that it would match the namespace of my other entities.